# Outlook add-in dev - VSTO vs Web, and is changing the form is possible?

Tags: c#, reactjs, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

It's my first time developing add in for outlook.
I saw that there is a way to develop add in in web technologies such as Angular, React, etc. This add in will work both on older version and new version of outlook?
If I want to develop also for Outlook 2007 | 2013, will add in developed in react will still work?

Another question I had, my add-in should change the current views

1. I want to add small marks on appointment on the calendar view (see the coloured dots on the meetings)
2. Add some insights in appointment invitations
3. Add custom field to new appointment form

I tried to look for solutions that change the views but found only solution that add custom forms and not changing the current form.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook add-ins are supported in Outlook 2013 or later for Windows, Outlook 2016 or later for Mac. More on [Supported hosts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#supported-hosts).
You will be limited to the certain [Extension points](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#extension-points). Extension points are the ways that add-ins integrate with Outlook. There is no way to customize Outlook interface with the add-in, instead you will be given the aria (pane, dialog) where you going to display your own UI and communicate with a form to enhance user experience.

If you need to support older Outlook clients and custom forms, you should stay with VSTO technology. Read more on ... [How are Office Add-ins different from COM and VSTO add-ins?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins?context=outlook/context#how-are-office-add-ins-different-from-com-and-vsto-add-ins)